# if statement keeps triggering

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am fairly new to C# (using it for a crpytographic process).
Some help would be greatly appreciated!

I have made a timer that should print out my hash speed every minute. See code below

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace HashConsoleApp {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      long Nonce = 19989878659;
      long Noncestart = 19989878659;
      int Tick = 0;
      DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

      while (Tick == 0) {
        string noncestr = Nonce.ToString();
        string plainData = "1" + noncestr + "Sjoerd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        string hashedData = ComputeSha256Hash(plainData);

        // if 10-zeroes hash is found, save to disk
        if (hashedData.Substring(0, 10) == "0000000000") {
          Tick = Tick + 1;
          string writestring = "Nonce: " + noncestr + "\n" + "hashed data: " + hashedData;
          System.IO.File.WriteAllText("hash_10.txt", writestring);
        }


        // print hash speed per second, each minute
        DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan span1 = end.Subtract(start);
        TimeSpan span2 = end.Subtract(start);
        if (span1.Minutes >= 1) {
          long diff = (int)(Nonce - Noncestart) / 60;
          string diffs = diff.ToString();
          Console.Write("Hash speed: " + diffs + " h/s");
          System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", Nonce.ToString());
          Noncestart = Nonce;
          span1 = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }


        // save Nonce every hour, reset clock
        if (span2.Minutes >= 60) {
          start = DateTime.UtcNow;
          System.IO.File.WriteAllText("hourly_nonce.txt", Nonce.ToString());
          span2 = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Raw data: {0}", plainData);   
        //Console.WriteLine("Hash {0}", hashedData);  
        //Console.WriteLine(ComputeSha256Hash("1"+noncestr+"Sjoerd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"));
      }
    }

    static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData) {
      // Create a SHA256   
      using(SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create()) {
        // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
        byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

        // Convert byte array to a string   
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
          builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, after the 1 minute mark this repeadetly keeps on printing on my screen. it looks like it gets stuck in the if statement. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: is there a loop somewhere, perhaps wrapping around (some of) this code?

Comment: `Minutes` just return the minute within the current hour. Did you mean TotalMinutes instead?

Comment: I just provided all of the code! hope it helps

Comment: You are declaring the `start` variable outside your `while` loop, so it never changes.
So once the current datetime is larger than your minute it will always trigger.

You must "reset" the `start` to the current datetime, once your minute has passed.

Comment: So, add `start = DateTime.UtcNow;` into your `if` block `if (span1.Minutes >= 1) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for your minute-timer (resetting `minuteStart` instead of `span1`):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    long Nonce = 19989878659;
    long Noncestart = 19989878659;
    int Tick = 0;
    DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime minuteStart = DateTime.UtcNow; // ##### (added)

    while (Tick == 0) {
        // [Process stuff]

        // print hash speed per second, each minute
        DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan span1 = end.Subtract(minuteStart); // ##### (modified)
        if (span1.TotalMinutes >= 1) { // ##### (modified but Minutes should work fine here)
            long diff = (int)(Nonce - Noncestart) / 60;
            string diffs = diff.ToString();
            Console.Write("Hash speed: " + diffs + " h/s");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", Nonce.ToString());
            Noncestart = Nonce;
            minuteStart = DateTime.UtcNow; // ##### (added)
            //span1 = TimeSpan.Zero; // ##### (deleted)
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

(See the lines with `// ####` comments)

The trick is that resetting `span1` is useless because of this line:

```
TimeSpan span1 = end.Subtract(start);
```

---

However, `if (span2.Minutes >= 60)` will never be entered, as [`TimeSpan.Minutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.minutes?view=netcore-3.1) "*ranges from **-59** through **59***".
You probably are looking for `TotalMinutes` here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (span1.Minutes >= 1) {` statement won't mean the printout only occurs once per minute, it will simply cause it to print whenever at least one minute has passed since the program started.

You need to check whether 1 minute has passed *since the last printout* . Therefore you need to reset the start time every time you run a printout. (N.B. Setting `span1 = TimeSpan.Zero` as you do now has no effect because you just overwrite that as soon as the loop runs again).

Also your minute and hour tests will conflict with each other once you do this, so you need separate date counters.

So add

```
DateTime start2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

just below the line where you declare `start` already.

Then please replace `span1 = TimeSpan.Zero;` with

```
start2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

and change `TimeSpan span1 = end.Subtract(start);`

to

```
TimeSpan span1 = end.Subtract(start2);
```

Lastly, replace `if (span2.Minutes >= 60) {` with

```
if (span2.TotalMinutes >= 60) {
```

otherwise this part won't work either because `Minutes` only reports the minutes in the current hour. You can also remove `span2 = TimeSpan.Zero;`, this is redundant like the similar line in the first `if` block.